# Python boto3 sort s3 objects by size

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

Is it possible in python (Boto3) or using any other python library to list objects in an s3 bucket based on their size.

I have 1000 files that I want to process by smallest files first

I tried using but I don't think it works this way

```
from operator import itemgetter
sortedobjects = sorted(source_bucket.objects.all(),key=itemgetter('size'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close! You just need to use `operator.attrgetter`, not `operator.itemgetter`, like this:

```
import boto3
from operator import attrgetter

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('your-bucket-here')
sortedobjects = sorted(bucket.objects.all(), key=attrgetter('size'))
```

Comment: sortedobjects = sorted(bucket.objects.all(), key=attrgetter('last_modified')) work too with this code!
thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3') 
response = client.list_objects(   
    Bucket='BucketName'
)
for object_size in response['Contents']:
    print((object_size['Key']), (object_size['Size']))
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.